# Certification for Lithium-battery-powered devices

Tags: lithium, certification

I am designing a device that would use a lithium battery inside, I have read that the battery should be certified with IEC 62133.

But my question now is: if I used a certified battery cell(s) in the product, should I also do any other certification or tests for the device itself as whole after integrating the battery into it to sell it in the EU or US?